# Type-inference for switch-case block with dynamic case strings

Tags: typescript

A tricky TS challenge.

Say one has two objects with a `type` property, and a specific property, `fooData` or `foo2Data`, that is specific to the `type` value of the object.

For example:

```js
const dynamicString: string = 'abc'

const fooTypeName = `foo${dynamicString}` as const // const fooTypeName: `foo${string}`
const foo2TypeName = `foo${dynamicString}2` as const // const foo2TypeName: `foo${string}2`

type FooObj = {
  type: typeof fooTypeName
  fooData: string
}

type Foo2Obj = {
  type: typeof foo2TypeName
  foo2Data: string
}
```

Say one unionizes the two object types, to create an "all possible objects" type, `AllObjs`:

```js
type AllObjs = FooObj | Foo2Obj
```

Now, say one wants to create a function that extracts the "data" value of an object typed as `AllObjs`. The sensible approach would be a switch-case block, as follows:

```js
const extractData = (obj: AllObjs) => {
  switch (obj.type) {
    case fooTypeName:
      return obj.fooData
    case foo2TypeName:
      return obj.foo2Data
    default:
      return null
  }
}
```

This currently errors. Typescript is not able to do type inference in the switch due to the specific chosen values for `fooTypeName` and `foo2TypeName`. If one appends any character other than `2` to `fooTypeName`, or prepends it with any character, it works. What is typescript doing here, and why?

I assume that it is something to do with set theory, and how `foo2TypeName` *could potentially* contain `fooTypeName`. However careful inspection of the code shows this to be impossible, because of the shared dependence on `dynamicString` (i.e. it is impossible to define `dynamicString` in such a way such that `fooTypeName` and `foo2TypeName` are the same).

Is Typescript just limited in this way?

## Edit

As @jcalz and @catgirlkelly explain, even though it is impossible for `fooTypeName` and `foo2TypeName` to be the same (no matter what value of `dynamicString`), because each reference to `dynamicString` is treated as anything, `foo${string}2` *contains* `foo${string}`, it is a compiler limitation that it does not treat the two strings as different, hence preventing type inference in the switch-case block.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/pt/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgTzAQwLYEtgGUoCd1gDmAXDNPkTALwwDkyARsLQFAsD0AVDAKpiipUAUzBQChGFAAWQmAyEAbEAHcYCgrORg4MAcNHiYIAK6xps8LPlLV6KCxjdl6BQpipkAa1lQIwGFLIAA5BCAA0MABmILhkIMIwuELIEOAAdA6c7BzsuuDQUSAgACoIQUIAcmiyNAAG0SAAJADeiCgY2HjiAL4AjLUwKXmQ9qAjhSVlldXUMPVFLW1omDgUhN0DQ2PQLNuwDQBMpeVVCXUNi0jLnWvdB5sQwzssUFMwAGJFAPIMAFazzQckimpFe5RAkQmx2mwiBDQAIsgoMhSORxCxumwwbJPiADj9-jRATBgeVQVMIRMjlNTkI4UUDojkaiukQMVi3gBBVwEx40XEEmAAHw+DIJbD2MCEAA88MhgFAmchZgAKEB-UjchS8gCU1AAfDBiWRnFBgFIYGq-mlsXrjSTgClZA1obTiECSSSklBjLgwEZrQikcgPbonVTXdV3Z7Pd7ff71b80oclaG4EJIshjAooNGY4khD6-TAwNmFEDMZigA)

Comment: I'm not seeing any error in that playground link, can you triple check that it's demonstrating what you intend to demonstrate?

Comment: ```foo${dynamicString}``` is ```foo${string}```, which is wider than ```foo${string}2```, and so TypeScript simplifies the type to just `foo${string}`. Adding that extra character at the end prevents this.

Comment: For all the compiler knows, both `fooTypeName` and `foo2TypeName` is (say) the string `"fooXYZ2"`.  That matches both `\`foo${string}\`` and `\`foo${string}2\`` types, so there's no way for it to eliminate one when it matches the other.  On the other hand, no string matches both `\`foo${string}1\`` and `\`foo${string}2\``, so you can use one to eliminate the other.  Does that make sense and fully address your question? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I have edited the question. If tsc considered the shared dependence of the two strings on `dynamicString`, then it would realize that it's impossible for either of the two strings to be the same, and be able to treat them as different types. Or at least I think. I can't think of a value of `dynamicString` that would cause the two strings to be the same. Is there no way to tell tsc to do this deeper consideration of the definition of the two strings?

Comment: Nope, `dynamicString` is typed as `string`. That's literally *any* string. Even ones that end in `2`, which would make `fooTypeName` indistinguishable from `foo2TypeName`.

Comment: Oh you're changing your question now. The compiler doesn't keep track of the *origin* / *identity* of the `fooTypeName` and `foo2TypeName` values; it just knows their *types*.  So, you could call this a limitation, just like it doesn't know that `(x: number) => x * x` can't return a negative number, or that `(x: string) => x + "!"` can't return an empty string.  Given that TS's compiler isn't a human-level intelligence, nor can it possibly spend the time to simulate every possible input/output, I'm not sure how it could be otherwise.

Comment: @catgirlkelly If `dynamicString` is `2`, then it's "foo2" and "foo22", which are different. If `dynamicString` is blank, similar idea. It does seem impossible to make them the same no matter what value of `dynamicString`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const dynamicString: string = 'abc'

// const fooTypeName = `foo${dynamicString}1` as const
const fooTypeName = `foo${dynamicString}` as const
const foo2TypeName = `foo${dynamicString}2` as const
```

`fooTypeName`'s type is

```
`foo${string}`
```

`foo2TypeName`'s type is

```
`foo${string}2`
```

`fooTypeName` is wider than `foo2Typename`, so TypeScript simplifies the union of the two to just `foo${string}`, disallowing you to discriminate the two constituents of `AllObjs`.

But why is it wider?

Consider the following case:

```
fooTypeName = "fooAnythingGoes2" // ✅ foo, followed by any string
foo2TypeName = "fooAnythingGoes2" // ✅ foo, followed by any string and then 2
```

Clearly, both assignments are valid, and they are the same. Now if we add any other character to the end of `fooTypeName`:

```
const fooTypeName = `foo${dynamicString}.` as const // foo${string}.
```

They're different:

```
fooTypeName = "fooAnythingGoes2" //  foo, followed by any string and then .
fooTypeName = "fooAnythingGoes." // ✅ foo, followed by any string and then .
foo2TypeName = "fooAnythingGoes2" // ✅ foo, followed by any string and then 2
```

More cases which might help you understand listed [here](https://tsplay.dev/WvEP4m).